# What is the proper meaning of 随便?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> 由于版权原因，Up主不能**随便**阅读别人的小说进行视频创作。

I looked up 随便, and there are 3 possible meanings,

> casual

> random

> informal

Which one do you think fits?

Comment: Could you provide wider context for this sentence? I ask this because Linguee provides this translation "For copyright reasons, Up owners cannot just read other people's novels for video creation.", with 随便 translated by "just", which seems to me finally more correct than other suggestions like "freely", "as one wishes", etc.

Comment: Something formal might be "at discretion", I feel…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 随便 can 'do as one wishes'

'freely' would be a suitable translation in this context

不能**随便**阅读别人的小说 - cannot **freely** read other people's novels

Answer (score 3):

None.

The [collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/chinese-english/%E9%9A%8F%E4%BE%BF) listed another one:

> do as one wishes

This seems to fit better here.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: in this case, "随便" just means

> help yourself

.